# Integral with radicals in the denominator. Have I proceeded the right way?

Tags: integration

I have this question:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt[3]{x}}$$

trying some u-sub
$u = \sqrt[6]{x} = x^{\frac{1}{6}}$ and $u^6 = x$ and $dx = 6u^5du$ and $u^2 = x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $u^3 = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$$\int \frac{6u^5}{u^3-u^2}$$

After doing long division, the fraction becomes $6u^2 + 6u + 6 + \frac{6u^5}{u^3-u^2}$
so
$$=6 \int u^2 + u + 1 + \frac{u^2}{u^3-u^2}$$

and the last fractional integral when simplified is $\int \frac{1}{x-1}$

Is this the right path? Ultimately, I get:

$$6(\frac{u^3}{3} + \frac{u^2}{2} + u + ln | x- 1|) + C$$ ???

Comment: Why don’t you plug your question into wolfram alpha to see if it’s correct? Or differentiate your result to see if you get back to the same function?

Comment: You are taking the right path. Do worry that you have $u$s and $x$s mixed up in your answer. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Same remark than Stan. Also you can simplify $\dfrac{6u^5}{u^3-u^2}=\dfrac{6u^3}{u-1}$ directly, but this of source end up in the same result. Except for that, your answer is correct.

Comment: Another remark, do not silence the $\mathop{dx}$ and $\mathop{du}$ in your notations, they are missing!